# Show custom fields on cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm trying to show custom fields on the cart but I'm missing something (and new to Commerce, so bear with me). When I output `{% for lineItem in cart.lineItems %}`  within my `{% for item in cart.lineItems %}` it outputs all the products again within the same line. How can I get the custom field to only show up on the line that is being output?

```
{% set lineItemHasErrors = false %}
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    {% if item.hasErrors() %}
        {# if the line item has errors lets record it so we can hide totals later (since they wont make sense) #}
        {% set lineItemHasErrors = true %}
    {% endif %}
    <tr class="item" {% if item.hasErrors() %}style="background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);"{% endif %}>
        <td>
            {% for lineItem in cart.lineItems %} 

            {% if lineItem.purchasable.product.type.hasVariants %}
              {% switch lineItem.purchasable.product.type %}
                {% case "wallpaper" %}
                    {#  Only output the varHeight if the product type is wallpaper #}
                    <strong>{{ lineItem.description }}</strong><br>
                    Height: {{ lineItem.purchasable.varHeight }}
                {% default %}
                    {{ lineItem.description }}
              {% endswitch %}

            {% else %}
                {#  Non variant purchasable  #}
                <strong>{{ lineItem.description }}</strong>

            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

            {% if item.options.material is defined %}
            <div class="select">
              <select name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][options][material]">
                <option value="no"
                        {% if item.options.material == 'PeelNStick' %}selected{% endif %}>
                    Peel N Stick
                </option>
                <option value="yes"
                        {% if item.options.material == 'PrePasted' %}selected{% endif %}>
                   Pre Pasted
                </option>
              <div class="select__arrow"></div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

            <br>
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="lineItems[{{ item.id }}][remove]"
                   value="1"> Remove Item
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>


        <td class="text-right">
            {% if not lineItemHasErrors %}
                {% if item.onSale %}
                    <s>Price: {{ item.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</s>
                    <br>
                    Sale Off: {{ item.saleAmount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                    <br>
                    Sale Price {{ item.salePrice|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                    <br>
                    Sale Price Subtotal: {{ item.subtotal|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    Price: {{ item.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                    <br>
                    Price Subtotal: {{ item.subtotal|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
                    <br>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% for sale in item.purchasable.sales %}
                {% if loop.first %}
                    Sales Applied:
                {% endif %}
                {{ sale.name }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% if not lineItemHasErrors %}
        {% for adjustment in item.adjustments %}
            <tr class="adjustment">
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <strong>{{ adjustment.type }} {{ adjustment.name }}</strong><br>({{ adjustment.description }}
                    )
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">{{ adjustment.amount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}


 {% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% for item in cart.lineItems %}` and `{% for lineItem in cart.lineItems %}` are the same loop - you're just assigning a different name to the iterable item! Just remove the inner loop and rename the inner variables to `item` instead of `lineItem`. Maybe I'm missing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That worked. I wasn't sure if they were separate elements. Thanks for clarifying. Still wrapping my head around Commerce.